# Counting reservations for each day, where res could span multiple days and should count for each day

Tags: mysql

I have a table with reservations in it. Each row is a reservation and has a `start` & `end` datetime field.

*I want to construct a query which gives me the count of reservations on each day in a certain time interval, eg april 2018.*

Selecting all the reservations within the given interval is fairly simple:

```
SELECT * FROM reservation 
WHERE start <= '2018-05-01 00:00:00' 
AND end >= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
```

But then the 'trouble' starts.
I want to display a 'count' of reservations on each day in the interval. But a reservation could span multiple days. So grouping them on `DAY(start)` is not correct.

I don't want to query each day in the interval seperately as this would be very server-intensive.

Is there a way to do this through a MySQL query?

Sample data:

```
id | start               | end 
2  | 2018-04-01 12:00:00 | 2018-04-03 09:00:00
3  | 2018-04-01 09:00:00 | 2018-04-01 11:00:00
4  | 2018-04-06 13:00:00 | 2018-05-20 09:00:00
```

Result for `2018-04-01` to `2018-04-06`:

```
2018-04-01 | 2   (2/3)
2018-04-02 | 1   (2)
2018-04-03 | 1   (2)
2018-04-04 | 0
2018-04-05 | 0 
2018-04-06 | 1   (4)
```

in a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e62ffa/2/0

Comment: Just to clarify, if a reservation spans to multiple days, (day 1 to 5 for example), then in the result we would have a count of 1 (at least) from day 1 to 5.

Comment: Jups. I'll add some sample data.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'll add a sqlfiddle shortly. No need to downvote or closevote; but sqlfiddle is having problems...

Comment: Normalization will definitely make it easy. Store each date separately in a different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we will reuse the answer from [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month#answer-97810). (You can use the *accepted* answer if you want, you would just need to create a dedicated table for that).

We will just modify the query a bit by using the condition that you need.

Your condition:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM reservation 
> WHERE start <= '2018-05-01 00:00:00' 
> AND end >= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
> ```

Modified answer from DBA Stackexchange:

```
SELECT date_field
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1) +
        INTERVAL (MONTH(NOW())-1) MONTH +
        INTERVAL daynum DAY date_field
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t * 10 + u daynum
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
            (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
            UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
        ORDER BY daynum
    ) AA
) AAA
/*WHERE MONTH(date_field) = MONTH(NOW())*/
WHERE date_field BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-05-01'
```

Take note that I only changed the `WHERE` Clause.

Now using that query as a `DERIVED TABLE`, we will include your `Reservations` table using `LEFT JOIN`.

```
 SELECT D.date_field
  , COUNT(R.Id)
  FROM (
    /* The query from above goes here */
  ) D
  LEFT JOIN Reservations R ON D.date_field BETWEEN DATE(R.StartDate) AND DATE(R.EndDate)
  GROUP BY D.date_field
```

Notice again that we used the `DATE` function to truncate the `TIME` part of our `StartDate` and `EndDate` <del>because for example, `2018-04-01` denotes the whole day and it cannot be in between `2018-04-01 09:00:00` and `2018-04-01 11:00:00`</del> for some *under the hood* reason I am not completely familiar of.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12c40/8) of the result.

If someone could help me on this one. `SELECT '2018-04-02' BETWEEN '2018-04-01 23:59:59' AND '2018-04-02 00:00:00'` will result to `1` (`TRUE`). It seems that by default `DATE` will have a `TIMESTAMP` of `00:00:00`.

### Update for More Flexible Date Range (2018-04-11)

The query above from [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month#answer-97810) only lists down the days of the **current month**. I tried to search a bit and found this [another good answer here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range/#answer-2157776). Here is a part of the query:

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (A.A+ (10 * B.A)) DAY AS Date
    FROM (
        SELECT 0 AS A UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
        UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) AS A
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 0 AS A UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
        UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) AS B
```

The query above will generate numbers (1 to 100) using `CROSS JOIN` and then subtracting it to the `Current Date`, then you will have dates from now up to 100 days back. You can add another `CROSS JOIN` of numbers to generate 1000 numbers if necessary.

I assume you will have `StartDate` and `EndDate` in your stored procedure or somewhere. We can replace the `CURDATE` with `EndDate` and then we will have 100 days back up to our `EndDate`. We will just add a `WHERE` clause to filter only the dates that we need using subquery/derived table.

```
SELECT D.Date
    FROM (
        SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (A.A+ (10 * B.A)) DAY AS Date
            FROM (
                SELECT 0 AS A UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
                UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
            ) AS A
            CROSS JOIN (
                SELECT 0 AS A UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
                UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
            ) AS B
    ) AS D
    WHERE D.Date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

We can now use `LEFT JOIN` to include the `Reservations` table.

Here is another **[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97c3b7/1)** for that. This also includes the Start and End Date variables, and a sample date range spanning from a previous year to the current year.

Again if you need more than 100 days of range, we will just need to add another `CROSS JOIN` of numbers, let's name that as `C`:

```
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS A UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) AS C
```

And then add it to the calculation of past days in the `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (A.A + (10 * B.A) + (100 * C.A)) DAY AS Date
```

Comment: There is a small glitch in your answer. If I change the start time to some where earlier (lets say dec 1st 2017) the query only starts from april first 2018. So the `WHERE date_field BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-05-01'` does not take the from dat into consideration.

Comment: @stUrb I updated my answer :) If this helps you, you can upvote again I think.